# Cannot stop running grails app after upgrading to Grails 4

Tags: grails

I used to work with Grails 3 for years now. Just started a new project on version 4.
In this version (not 100% sure if it's version related), when I start the app with `grails run-app` it runs, but I can't stop it with the regular `Ctrl + c`. 
The only way that I can stop it is by killing the java process.

Did anyone experienced this issue?

I am on Mac OS Catalina and running the app from iTerm terminal.

Comment: Can you include the version of grails, jdk, macosx, etc? I can't reproduce this with jdk8/11, with 4.0.1 on osx 10.15. You may want to turn up to debug or trace and see if something in your app is getting stuck in the shutdown hook

Comment: Please check out this thread: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10791 and especially double check `JAVA_HOME`